# MySQL select latest records from different sources

Tags: php, mysql, join, subquery

I'm working with a currency rate DB in which there are rates for multiple currencies fetched from multiple sources.

I'm trying to build a query which fetches the last two records for each currency from each source.
In total there are about 60 currencies fetched from 10 different sources.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.iso4217, c.flag,
            r1.buy, r1.sell, r1.amount, r1.time
            FROM currencies c
            JOIN rates r1 ON r1.currency = c.id
            JOIN src s ON s.id = r1.src
            WHERE c.status = 10
            AND s.status = 10
            AND r1.id IN (
                SELECT id
                FROM
                (
                SELECT r2.id
                    FROM
                    rates r2
                    WHERE
                    r2.currency = c.id
                    AND r2.src = s.id
                    ORDER BY r2.id
                    DESC LIMIT 2
                )alias
            )
```

This query won't run and just ends up returning

> Unknown column 'c.id' in 'where clause'

It does work perfectly fine and giving me the data I want if I manually sets

```
r2.currency = #
AND r2.src = #
```

to any ids in the innermost subquery.

How can I pass c.id and s.id to the subquery?

Comment: Is there an `id` column in `currencies`?

Comment: Yes there is an id column in that table, primary index.